# Microsoft-excel: If column G of row (of any row within the selection) is not empty, add character ❚ in front of column A and column G

Tags: microsoft-excel

From this [website](https://www.exceltip.com/tips/add-a-character-to-every-cell.html), we can understand that we can obtain the `❚` in front of any number within the selection by using:

`\❚ #` as custom number formatting.

Can we adapt this to achieve the following:

---

### Example

Imagine this is the file:

[image]

This is what should be done:

[image]

---

Assumption: the only possibilities for cells in column G, to begin with are:

- blank
- a number

We are interested in when the cell for any given row in column G is not blank (= when it is a number).

---

So the question is:

- If cell of column G of row is not empty (and is a number, which ... let's assume automatically is the case)
- And if cell of column A **of that same row** is not empty (does not need to be a number)

⬇ Then ⬇

- Add character ❚ in front of cell in column A and cell in column G.

---

To summarize:

The receiving of a ❚ for column A should depend on whether or not there is a value in column G, as well as on whether or not column A is empty.

The receiving of a ❚ for column G should also depend on whether or not there is a value in column G, as well as on whether or not column A is empty.

Answer (score 1):

One way can you achieve both questions is by using conditional formatting. You will need to create 2 rules: the first for column G and the second for column B.

For column G, Create a rule to a cell value not equal to `""` (empty). Click on Format, then Custom then enter `❚ #` your custom . Then Ok, OK, OK.

[image: IMG:]

For column G, Create a rule to a cell value not equal to `""` (empty). Click on Format, then Custom then enter `❚ @` your custom . Then Ok, OK, OK.

[image: IMG:]

EDIT: To cater for the case when a cell in column A is empty while a cell on the same row in column G is not empty, add another conditional formatting rule for column G that uses the formula: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-6))`. Move it to be the first rule and select "Stop if True"

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

The result will be as shown on the image below:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Apply the logic using conditional formatting. Column A is an example in my case. In you case, you should select column G, and apply your custom format.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I will delete this answer and will make changes based on your screenshot(s).

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen See edit.

Comment: The receiving of a ❚ for column A should depend on whether or not there is a value in column G, as well as on whether or not column A is empty.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I saw that part after posting/sending my comment. I am writing a new rule for that case.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen See edit